# Is there a way to get an interface ID of a Solidity interface using ethersjs?

Tags: solidity, interfaces, ethers.js, eip-165

Is there a way to get an interface ID of a Solidity interface using ethersjs? I'm using ethersjs in my test file and I want to test if the `supportsInterface` is returning a correct interface ID.

I could get the interface ID in Solidity with `type(IMyContract).interfaceId` but it doesn't seem like there is a straightforward way of achieving the same thing outside of Solidity.

How can I get the interface ID of a contract or interface in ethersjs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there is not. You have to xor all function selectors of `IMyContract`.

To make your life easier, you can use ethers.js [interface](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/abi/interface/#Interface) and use its `getSighash` functions to not have to hash it and slice it ourself. But still you have to xor these selectors to get an `interfaceId`.

Comment: How do I xor the hashes in ethersjs? I don’t think I can use ^ to do that like in solidity.

Comment: No, you need to use BigNumber framework: `ethers.BigNumber.from(foo1Selector).xor(ethers.BigNumber.from(foo2Selector))`. Or at least thats how I do that.

Answer (score 7):

Here's how I solved it, Ethers v5 & Typescript with OpenZeppelin upgradeable contracts (will work with any type of contract).

```
import { Contract, ContractInterface, ethers } from "ethers";
import { IERC1155Upgradeable__factory } from "../typechain-types/factories/IERC1155Upgradeable__factory";
import { IERC165Upgradeable__factory } from "../typechain-types/factories/IERC165Upgradeable__factory";

    const IERC165UpgradeableInterface = IERC165Upgradeable__factory.createInterface();
    const IERC1155UpgradeableInterface = IERC1155Upgradeable__factory.createInterface();
    const IERC165InterfaceID = getInterfaceID(IERC165UpgradeableInterface)
    // interface ID does not include base contract(s) functions.
    const IERC11InterfaceID = getInterfaceID(IERC1155UpgradeableInterface).xor(IERC165InterfaceID);
    assert(await contract.supportsInterface(IERC11InterfaceID._hex), "Doesn't support IERC1155Upgradeable");

export function getInterfaceID(contractInterface: ethers.utils.Interface) {
  let interfaceID: ethers.BigNumber = ethers.constants.Zero;
  const functions: string[] = Object.keys(contractInterface.functions);
  for (let i=0; i< functions.length; i++) {
      interfaceID = interfaceID.xor(contractInterface.getSighash(functions[i]));
  }

  return interfaceID;
}
```

The tricky part is that you have to xor out any base contracts as I looked though the solc compiler and they do not include base contract functions.

Comment: This is just an addition to @gvtopcoder sometimes the length of the the interfaceID._hex output is to short. you can add ```interfaceID._hex.padEnd(10, '0')```. This will make sure that the supportsInterfaceInput is always correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind to have a selector hardcoded, I would use the remix to get the selector. In particular, I would insert an interface of your contract into the remix and create another contract with a public variable with the `type(IMyContract).interfaceId` value assigned (see below). Then deploy the contract and get the value of the selector from the "DEPLOY & RUN TRANSACTIONS" panel.

Here is the workaround:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

interface IMyContract {
    function func1() external view returns (bytes32);
    function func2() external;
}

contract GetSelectorOfIMyContract {
    bytes4 public _interfaceId;
    constructor () {
        _interfaceId = type(IMyContract).interfaceId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a simple app to solve this problem(I had the same issue so i had to solve it).
https://interfaceid.lucasgrasso.com.ar/ , You just have to paste the ABI of the Interface you want to have the ID to.
Hope it´s useful.

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged. If the site stops working the answer isn't useful. It would be nice if you show the code used to generate the id.